# Chicken-and-egg for assembly needed for T4 template

Tags: c#, dependencies, t4

What's a nice way to have in a T4 template a reference to an assembly that is referenced by the project ? The reference was installed through NuGet.

Once the project successfully builds, the assembly can be found in $(TargetDir), but before it builds, they are not there. Copying the dlls from  SolutionDir\packages manually kinda works, but is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it from the package folder. For example,

`SolutionDir\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

The problem here is that if you update the nuget package it will break the reference.

Comment: Indeed, I had thought of that and with the hardcoded version strings it looks fragile. Thanks anway